# Normalization and Tables in MySql

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, database, database-design

I know that the following question is probably "opinion based", but since I am creating my first DBMS I need advice.

I Have a table for "Subscription" with the following columns:

```
IDSubscription_PK, Date_Subscription, Cost_Subscription.
```

The cost of subscription varies according to the months of subscription (ex-> 3 months: 30$, 6 months: 60$ and so on from 1 to 12 months)

Knowing that I am pursuing 3rd normal form, would you recommend me to create two separate tables, like that:

```
Subscription -> IDSubscription_PK, Date_Subscription, Months_Subscription
Costs -> Months_Subscription, Cost
```

And so, I will have :

```
SUBSCRIPTION_TABLE                |    COST_TABLE
IDSub.   Date.        Months.     |. Months.  Cost
2992.   2019/07/12.    1          |.  1.       10
9178.   2020/01/11.    10         |.  2.       20
1827.   2020/03/21.    7          |.  ...     ....
1928.   2020/11/10.    1          |.  12.      120
```

Or, instead, a single one, as follows:

```
Subscription -> IDSubscription_PK, Date_Subscription, Date_end_Subscription, cost
```

and so:

```
SUBSCRIPTION_TABLE              
IDSub.   Date.        EndOfSub    Cost 
2992.   2019/07/12.   2019/08/12   10
9178.   2020/01/11.   2020/11/11   100    
1827.   2020/03/21.   2020/10/21   70   
1928.   2020/11/10.   2020/12/10   10
```

Comment: In your first idea, what type and data would contain "Months_Subscription"?

Comment: an Int between 1 and 12 @Alejandro

Comment: Please see: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you add the `cost` table. Why?

Without it you would have to do some sort of `SELECT DISTINCT` operation on the `subscription` table to get a price list. And that might generate rubbish if some subscribers had unique deals. Generally, if you must do `SELECT DISTINCT` or something like that to get information you need, it's a sign of denormalization.

Better yet, I suggest **a `plan` table** in place of your `cost` table.

It would contain these sorts of entries

```
plan_id   months  cost  description
   1        1      10   Monthly plan
   2        1       5   Monthly plan, student discount
   3       12     100   Yearly plan
   4       12      35   Yearly plan, student discount
```

This gives you the flexibility to have variations in prices as your business requires, in a table-driven rather than logic-driven fashion.

Then, your `subscription` table would look something like this.

```
subscription_id  plan_id subscriber_id renewal_date 
   1                1       101         2020-05-05
   2                4       103         2021-04-05
```

And, it's easy to get your price list:  `SELECT * FROM plan`.

**Pro tip**: Avoid using mixed upper and lower case in the names of tables and columns. The case-sensitivity rules for MySQL are different when the server is hosted on different operating systems, and you do not want to deal with that problem now or in the future.  All lower case: no problem.

**Pro tip**: It's common to name a table for the entity in the table, like `plan` or `subscription`. Then, name the autoincrementing PK of the table `plan_id` or `subscription_id` or `whatever_id`. When you use the same id as a FK in some other table, use that same `whatever_id` name for it. This makes life *much* easier for somebody who must read and maintain your SQL in future.

Comment: That's clear, thank you! I have 2 questions: in the "subscription table", what does "subscription_id" stand for? (cause I see two equal numbers) and the second one: Why the "plan table" is preferred to the "cost table" I put in the example (since there no discounts for students or something like that, I would have 12 different plans (1 month, 2 months...12 months)

Comment: The two identical `subscription_id` values were a mistake on my part. Fixed; thanks for pointing it out. The `plan` table doesn't require you to have multiple subscription plans, but it does allow you to.  I don't think it makes much sense to use a number of months as the pointer to a cost. It's simply not very flexible. This is from my experience running a real subscription service, pulling in about USD1million per year.

Comment: So I can create two tables: CUSTOMER and PLAN , and a third table (an associative entity), whose primary keys are PlanID, CustomerID and Date? (also "Date" should be a PK since the same customer can subscribe to the same plan more than once, so there should be also date as identifier) Do you think it's a good solution?

Comment: Or instead, this third table may have a specific PK (for example, subscription ID), and PlanID an customer ID as foreign keys. This solution or the previous one?

Answer (score 1):

Regardless of the details of the `subscription` table, you need to put the actual cost in the user's table.  Tomorrow, you may change the rates.  So, you should *not* have the user table point to the subscription table.

Or...

The subscription table could have a range of days during which it applied.  When you change the price, you add new rows to that table.  New (or renewed) subscriptions will link to the new rows.  But... This model is messy to implement; I prefer the other approach.